# Images forced with [!htb] show up at end of chapter

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

My images show up at the end of the chapter (only happens in one chapter), even though I use strict float parameters `[!htpb]` or only `[h!]`. I would like them to show up in the text on the (almost) precise position where I've placed them. (and yes, I have used `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{float}`).

Example of image input:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/Part II/II-1_vitruvius.jpg}
\caption{Vitruvius' principles}
\label{fig:II.1_Vitruvius}
\end{figure}
```

Weird thing is that no errors show up. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[!htb]` as used in the title mostly has the effect of preventing the float being on a float page (as it has no p) so going to the end is quite likely/ `[h!]` even more so (latex usually warns that it is changing this to `ht`)

Comment: The float moving is not an error, the only purpose of the figure environment is to allow it to move. where it moves to depends on the size of the float and the content on the surrounding pages, and you gave no indication about either/. But I suspect your question is a duplicate of...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: From the "official documentation" for how floats work: "if a letter is not present then the corresponding area will not be tried at all."  See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)  (But the question cited by @DavidCarlisle should be considered the duplicate.)